# xmessage and cron

Tags: cron

simple cron bash script which uses xmessage to alert the user to a specific condition.  It works fine and does exactly as expected when I run it, but when I fire it off via cron, I get in syslog:

`(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`

What am I doing wrong?

ETA:
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# script to capture current battery percentage and display in an alert dialog box
# displays alert only if percentage is less than 10%

export DISPLAY=":0"

percentage=$(upower -i $(upower -e | grep '/battery') | grep --color=never -E percentage|xargs|cut -d' ' -f2|sed s/%//)

if [[ $percentage -lt 99 ]]
then

   xmessage -buttons Ok:0 -geometry 500X500 -nearmouse "BATTERY IS AT $percentage%" -timeout 30
   
fi
```

I do not get the MTA error unless the xmessage line is executed.
PS, yes, the 10% and 99% dont match, I set it to 99 for troubleshooting.

Comment: "info" is a note not an error; and as stated you do not have a MTA installed. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog  (mta=mail transfer agent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)" error in the syslog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog)

Comment: `xmessage` is X-based ... i.e. requires a user's X session(*You might manage to run it with CRON if you specify a display environment variable e.g. DISPLAY=":0" before your command*) ... Please se similar question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1450604/968501

Answer (score 1):

The information message:

```bash
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Is not your issue ... It simply means that your crnjob resulted in an output that you didn't provide a method for it to be redirected/handled(*Notice: That output could be some useful information and maybe you should redirect it to a file for later inspection*) and CRON in this case tries to email the output but doesn't succeed due to absence of MTA(*Mail Transfer Agent*) ... It's totally a normal behavior and installing an MTA will not make your cronjob execute better ... Please see [Cron job log reads 'No MTA installed', does that prevent the CRON job from finishing?](https://askubuntu.com/q/892599)

Your issue, most likely, is that [`xmessage`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xmessage.1.html) is an X-based application that requires an X server user session already running plus a display interface/server specified ... If your cronjob is guaranteed to run while an X server user session is already running and not otherwise, then you might be able to make it work if you find and specify the address of your display interface/server as an environment variable before your command in the crontab e.g. like so:

```bash
* * * * * DISPLAY=":0" your_command ...
```

You can see your current environment `$DISPLAY` variable while your user X session is running e.g. like so:

```bash
echo $DISPLAY
```

and even though, CRON might run your command before an X user session is even fully initiated in case of e.g. `@reboot` is specified or the user has logged out their session for some reason at the time CRON runs your command.

Notice also that if you add your command to `root`'s crontab with `sudo crontab -e` then your X-based application might not run no matter what you do as `root` on Ubuntu, by default, can't start an X session.

Therefore given the above reasons, CRON is **not** by all means the preferred way for running X-based user applications.

**Otherwise**, I recommend you run your X-based script/command as [a startup application](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321) ... Please see [Startup script not executing](https://askubuntu.com/q/1450604/968501) for similar issue and possible workaround.

Also, please see [Battery Full Indicator 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1411483) for an example of a battery monitoring script that can be used in a startup application instead of a cronjob.